# Hybris SAP CPQ getting sample data

Tags: mocking, sap-commerce-cloud, sap-erp

I installed SAP CPQ on  hybris 6.2.

I got some sample data about WCMS but not all about products.

I created them but ,after some configurations , the code needed the knowledge base coming from SAP ERP through the data loader.

Since we don't have yet the possibility to connect to SAP ERP,my question is: is it possible to mock it or to create manually the data.

At the moment I'm not even sure if the knowledge base resides in the "second" database or in the main one(I can check)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably too late, but for others who might have the same question.

Last thing first, the knowledge base resides in the "second", CPQ database, not in the main hybris DB.

Now about the mock knowledge base data. If you don't have a possibility to connect your CPQ to SAP ERP to load KB data, then you can use **Eclipse SME add-on** to maintain your knowledge bases.

1. Go to https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/softwarecenter and search for "SOLCONF SME" keyword. You will see two software categories:

   - FBS_SOLCONF_SME 1.0
   - FBS_SOLCONF_SME 2.0
2. Go with the second categorie and find SP05, which is the latest version at the moment. Download **FBSSOLCONFSME05_0-70000659.ZIP** ZIP file, unzip it and install the add-on as described in the chapter 8 of "SAP Configure, Price, and Quote for Solution Sales Configuration" guide available here: https://help.sap.com/viewer/p/SAP_CONFIGURE_PRICE_AND_QUOTE_FOR_SOLUTION_SALES_CONFIGURATION
3. In Eclipse, Windows->Preferences, find "SAP CPQ for Solution Sales" item, go to "Connections" and create a new Database connection. **Note that SME is case-sensitive to the name of databse if you are running on MS SQL.**
4. Create your KB (this is another big topic how to do it, and I'll leave it out of the scope of this answer).
5. Once your KB is ready, in Eclipse go to File -> Export -> SAP CPQ for  Solution Sales Configuration -> Export Knowledge Base. Click "Next", select your KB, then "Next" again, provide your SQL user password and click "Finish". Now your KB shall be exported to your CPQ database and be available in hybris CPQ.